# Rolling Average number of visitors by Location ID and Date using dplyr in R

Tags: r

I have a DataFrame df which has three columns:

1. store_ID
2. Date
3. Number_of_Customers

For each store ID, there is one row for every date in a consecutive date range, and the number of customers visiting the store on that date.

For each store_ID I want to calculate the 5 day rolling average number of customers visiting that store.

I have tried things like

```
 df<- df%>%group_by(store_ID)%>%
    mutate(rollavg=rollmean(Number_of_Customers, 5, na.pad = TRUE))
```

This seems like it should work but does not seem to give me the correct values in the rollavg column.

What am I missing?

Comment: Is it possible that some days don't have data? For example, if we want to calculate the rolling average for January 5th, we need data for January 1 - January 5th. What should be done if there isn't any data for some date in that range?

Comment: The data is complete

Comment: Is the desired output the average of the last five values for each date?

Comment: Yes that’s what I’m trying to get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using `zoo::rollmean()`. The problem is that you are calculating a moving average - that is, the average is centered on each date. You want it to be right aligned. This is controlled by the parameter `align`, whose default value in this function is `"center"`.

You could read more about this by running `?rollapply`, which is the underlying function used by `rollmean()`.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(zoo)
df = df %>% 
  arrange(store_ID, Date) %>% 
  group_by(store_ID) %>%
  mutate(rollavg = rollmean(Number_of_Customers, 5, align = "right", fill = NA))
```

You may have already done this, but you should ensure the data is arranged by `Date`. I've added it above for completeness. Also note that `na.pad` is deprecated and should be replaced by `fill = NA` in this case.

Comment: Thanks, this solution did exactly what I needed!

Comment: Note that there is rollmeanr with an r on the end that defaults to right alignment.